# How to read .git/index file for submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have `test` folder in which I'm adding a submodule and after that I manually delete the `.gitmodules` file from the folder and then again want to add the submodule but facing error like  `'test' already exists in the index` if I have multiple submodules and they don't have `.gitmodule` file how we will identify that they are submodules or not? If this question is silly please sorry because I'm very new to git. I suggested by someone for [link](http://%20https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) but not able to make a command which identifies this. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `test` folder, but is this your top level git repo? If there's a `test/.git` folder, then it's a git repo.

You probably should not be deleting the `test/.gitmodules` file - what were you trying to accomplish here?

`'test' already exists in the index` - Indeed, if you attempt to add the same submodule again, you may get an error like that.

`I have multiple submodules and they don't have .gitmodule file - how will we identify that they are submodules or not?` - Submodules are not aware that they are submodules. When you change them, you'll see that the submodule is "dirty" inside the top level/superproject's git status.

If you use git subrepo, which is much easier for newcomers, you'll notice each "sub repo" has some sort of `.gitrepo` file inside of it, indicating it's a subrepo.

If you are new to git, checkout git subrepo, git submodules are not for the faint of heart. https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo

I recommend starting *from scratch* with a new git repo. If you have unpushed changed in your project, copy paste those into a newly/freshly cloned repo. Then carefully follow setup instructions for git-subrepo.